# Remove "regex duplicates" from ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to "clean" an ArrayList in java, here is the explanation

Assuming we have this list :

```
a = ["a_12_b", "a_13_b", "a_13bis_b", "a_14_b", "a_14_new_b"]
```

In this list, `"a_13bis_b"` and `"a_14_new_b"` are considered as duplicates, Why ? because each entry have this regex : `a_ "a string with a lenght =2" _b`

The output should be :

```
a = ["a_12_b", "a_13_b", "a_14_b"]
```

I used this simple code, but it returns wrong output :

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            //basically clean entry will remove the a_ and _b
            String value1= cleanEntry(list.get(j));
            for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
                    String value2= cleanEntry(list.get(k));
                    if (k != j && value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2)) {
                        duplicates.add(list.get(k))
                        list.remove(k);
                    }
            }
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: Try to add some `debug print`s to your program. For example you should output what element you are currently processing and what actions this triggered. I think the problem is that, after removing some found duplicates, you also will traverse those duplicates in the next iterations because they are contained in your outer `list` loop. You should not traverse duplicates anymore, else they will be considered as `value1` and thus mark previous elements as duplicates.

Comment: Actually yes, when I pasted my code, and changed some variables name, I forgot to change this line noDuplicates.remove(k); by list.remove(k);

But it didn't work

Comment: Code edited after your comment, thanks

Comment: Sure that this actually works? Looks like it should throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can not modify a list while iterating it. However you can remember the values and remove them afterwards and just skip them while iterating.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stream map method with a regular expression to "normalize" the strings to a common format and then create a set out of the normalized strings.

Something like this:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a_12_b", "a_13_b", "a_13bis_b", "a_14_b", "a_14_new_b");
Set<String> uniques = a.stream()
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("^([a-z]_\\d{2})[^\\d].+(_[a-z])$", "$1$2"))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(uniques);
```

This prints:

> [a_14_b, a_13_b, a_12_b]

Solution for Java 7, 6:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a_12_b", "a_13_b", "a_13bis_b", "a_14_b", "a_14_new_b");
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(String s : a) {
    set.add(s.replaceAll("^([a-z]_\\d{2})[^\\d].+(_[a-z])$", "$1$2"));
}
System.out.println(set);
```

Result:

> [a_12_b, a_13_b, a_14_b]

If you need more than 2 numeric characters, you can change the regular expression. Here is an example with result:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a_12345678901234567890123456_b", "a_13345678901234567890123456_b",
                "a_13345678901234567890123456bis_b", "a_14345678901234567890123456_b", "a_14345678901234567890123456_new_b");
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(String s : a) {
    set.add(s.replaceAll("^([a-z]_\\d{26})[^\\d].+(_[a-z])$", "$1$2"));
}
System.out.println(set);
```

Result:

> [a_12345678901234567890123456_b, a_13345678901234567890123456_b,
>   a_14345678901234567890123456_b]

Comment: This can only be used in JRE 8 ?

Comment: Added solution for Java version less than 8.

Comment: Thanks, how can I adapt this code to have it working with a string with 26 caracters, and how can I get the list of duplicates ?

Thanks again

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example for 26 characters. Assuming that you mean 26 digits after the first underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply discard all the characters after 2nd character before comparison.
Try this..

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    //basically clean entry will remove the a_ and _b
    String value1= cleanEntry(list.get(j));
    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
        String value2= cleanEntry(list.get(k));
        if (k != j && value1.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase(value2.substring(0,2))) {
            duplicates.add(list.get(k)) list.remove(k);
        }
    } 
}
```